# how to use reusable code for Google Cloud Function Firestore trigger?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

sorry, I am new in backend development. I usually create express middleware to perform the same action over and over again in Node JS

like for example, if I want to check if the request has valid authorization as the restaurant owner or not, then I create a middleware like this

```
const restaurantOwnerOnlyMiddleware = async (req, res, next) => {
    const {restaurantId} = req.params;
    const user = req.user;

    const restaurantDoc = await db.collection("restaurants").doc(restaurantId).get(); // db-read
    const restaurant = restaurantDoc.data();

    if (restaurant.owner !== req.user.uid) {
        res.status(403).send("Unauthorized");
        return;
    }
  
    req.restaurant = restaurant; 

    next();
};
```

and then use the middleware in the desired route

```
app.put("/:restaurantId/stars", [restaurantOwnerOnlyMiddleware], (req, res) => {
    

    // do something
  
    res.send();
});
```

now for example I want to use Firestore trigger in cloud function, I want to perform something after a menu is created, but this action is only for verified restaurant owner

```
exports.createMenu = functions.firestore
    .document('restaurant/{restaurantID}/menu/{menuId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {


    // after a menu is created 
    // then if the menu creator is verified restaurant owner, then do something in here
   
     

});
```

so **checking verified restaurant owner** will be performed multiple times, not only in this firestore trigger, but also I will use it in other firestore triggers or even in storage triggers. in Node JS I usually create a middleware

but how to make reusable authorization checking like this in Cloud Function?

it is better if I only make once and use it in multiple places. how to do that?

I am using typescript, but javascript is ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An important note before going forward, remember that just because the document `restaurant/{restaurantID}/menu/{menuId}` exists, does NOT mean that `restaurant/{restaurantID}` does as you can [delete a document, without deleting it's subcollections](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#delete_documents).

Depending on why you need to know that a user is the owner, you can also use [Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview) and [Cloud Storage Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security) to secure your documents and files.

For the create menu function, you'd likely be doing the following:

```
exports.createMenu = functions.firestore
  .document('restaurant/{restaurantID}/menu/{menuId}')
  .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    const restaurantSnapshot = await admin.firestore().doc(`restaurant/${context.params.restaurantID}`).get();
    
    if (!restaurantSnapshot.exists) {
      console.error('Linked restaurant does not exist');
      return;
    }
    
    if (uid === restaurantSnapshot.get('owner')) {
      console.log('Current user is not owner');
      /* do something */
      return;
    }
    
    console.log('Current user is owner, and linked restaurant data exists');
    /* do something */
  });
```

We can extract this out into a function to become:

```
// returns `true` when 'restaurant/{restaurantID}' exists AND it's owner is the same as the given user ID
async function isUserOwnerOfRestaurant(uid, restaurantID) {
  const restaurantSnapshot = await admin.firestore().doc(`restaurant/${restaurantID}`).get();
  return uid === restaurantSnapshot.get('owner');
}

exports.createMenu = functions.firestore
  .document('restaurant/{restaurantID}/menu/{menuId}')
  .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    if (await isUserOwnerOfRestaurant(context.auth.uid, context.params.restaurantID)) {
      console.log('Current user is not owner');
      return;
    }
    
    console.log('Current user is owner, and linked restaurant data MAY exist');
    /* do something */
  });
```

An important note here is that using the `isUserOwnerOfRestaurant` will return `false` when `restaurant/${restaurantID}` doesn't exist. This means that you might be creating a menu for a non-existent restaurant.

If it's important that the restaurant data actually exists, we can move on to the following:

```
// returns the restaurant's data if 'restaurant/{restaurantID}' exists AND it's owner is the same as the given user ID, otherwise throws an error
async function assertUserOwnerAndGetRestaurantData(uid, restaurantID) {
  const restaurantSnapshot = await admin.firestore().doc(`restaurant/${restaurantID}`).get();
  
  if (!restaurantSnapshot.exists) {
    throw new Error('restaurant-not-found');
  }
  
  if (uid !== restaurantSnapshot.get('owner')) {
    throw new Error('user-not-owner');
  }
  
  return restaurant.data();
}

exports.createMenu = functions.firestore
  .document('restaurant/{restaurantID}/menu/{menuId}')
  .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    const restaurantData = await assertUserOwnerAndGetRestaurantData(context.auth.uid, context.params.restaurantID);
    
    // if here, restaurant exists AND the current user is the owner AND
    //          restaurantData contains the data for the restaurant just in case it's useful
    
    console.log('Current user is owner, and linked restaurant data exists');
    /* do something */
  });
```

Now, if you were to use this for a Cloud Storage trigger with file metadata, you can use:

```
exports.newFileUploaded = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) => {
  const filePathParts = object.name.split('/');
  const fileMetadata = object.metadata; // insert user's ID here (or better yet - their ID token), see https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#add_file_metadata
  
  if (filePathParts[0] == 'restaurant') {
    // new restaurant file
    const restuarantId = filePathParts[1]; // assuming restaurant/{restuarantId}/some/file/path.png
    const restuarantData = await assertUserOwnerAndGetRestaurantData(fileMetadata.uid, restuarantId);
    // if here, restaurant exists AND user ID in the metadata is the owner AND
    //          restaurantData contains the data for the restaurant just in case it's useful
    
    // do something with file, like generate thumbnails, update restaurant and menu info in Firestore, etc.
    return;
  }
  
  console.log(`No action needed for file at ${object.name}.`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use Firestore Security Rules**

You should use [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) along with [Firestore security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions) to achieve the result you want.

Here's a simple `firestore security rule` that allows the *Firebase authenticated user* to access documents from `restaurant` based on the following

- Allow `READ` if user is authenticated
- Allow `WRITE` if `restaurant.owner` is the same as the authenticated user's `uid`

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /restaurant/{document=**} {
        allow write: if request.auth != null && 
            request.auth.uid == resource.data.owner;
        allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

**Authorization in Firebase Cloud function triggers**

Since, triggers are run based on a condition like **a document is created** in `/restaurant/{restaurantID}/menu/`, you **should check authorization on the document creation** part itself.

That way, if the document is created, then the user must be authorized. Then the **trigger** code will run.

However, if you are creating **http callable cloud functions**, then you can check user authentication there using the **Firebase AdminSDK to authenticate Firebase user tokens** (or any of your preferred authentication strategies) in the function.

**Note**

Check out [Firebase authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) and [Firestore security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions) in details as they allow a broad scope of functionalities.